# Why is transform changing the titles of my columns?

Tags: r, time

All I am trying to do is to create a variable that converts MM:SS to seconds. I am able to create that variable successfully, but it also converts all of the symbols (such as ( or /) in my column names to dots. After running the final line of the following code, RStudio changes the names of my columns to XXX.XXX.XXX. For example, VO2(ml/kg/min) is changed to VO2.ml.kg.min.

```
#Rename Columns
df <- df %>% 
  rename("Time" = "t",
         "VT(l)" = "VT",
         "VE(l/min)" = "VE",
         "VO2(ml/min)" = "VO2",
         "VCO2(ml/min)" = "VCO2",
         "VO2(ml/kg/min)" = "VO2/Kg",
         "Stage" = "Marker",
         "Ti(s)" = "Ti",
         "Te(s)" = "Te",
         "Ttot(s)" = "Ttot",
         "CO2et(mmHg)" = "PaCO2_e")
summary(df)

#Create a function to convert time to seconds
time2sec <- function(x) {
  with(as.POSIXlt(x, format = "%Y:%M:%S"), 3600 * (year + 1900) + 60 * min + sec)
}

#Create a column with converted time
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Seconds=NA,
         .after=Time)
summary(df)

#Fill Seconds with numbers
df <- transform(df, Seconds = time2sec(df$Time))
summary(df)
```

I was trying to create a column of seconds and it changed my titles.

Comment: Hi, it's hard to help you without having access to your data structure. If you can, please include the output of `dput(df)` in a code chunk in your question. In the meantime, try to apply `time2sec()` in the mutate call above the `transform()`: `df %>% mutate(Seconds=time2sec(Time), .after=Time)`.